# Call a function decorated with a particular attribute

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, attributes

I'm writing a debug menu API for Unity and I'm trying to replicate some of the behavior of the ContextMenu attribute. This attribute looks like this

`[ContextMenu("Debug Function Name")]`

This puts a debug item into the dropdown list for a component and clicking it will execute the method that the attribute is decorating. In the constructor for my attribute, I want to pass the name and the method through to my debug manager to construct the debug menu with.

I can't see how Unity does this though. As far as I know, the attribute class can't get information about the method so is the only option here to use reflection to find classes in the executing assembly that have that attribute attached?

Comment: *(...) is the only option here to use reflection to find classes in the executing assembly that have that attribute attached?* I'd say the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so is the only option here to use reflection to find classes in the executing assembly that have that attribute attached?

Yes. Unity loops through every loaded assembly -> every type -> every method -> if it has a [ContextMenu] attribute -> do stuff with the MethodInfo + attribute.

The attribute doesn't know anything about its target, but the only way to get an attribute is to get it from its target, so you have access to them both anyway.

Comment: Figured as much. Thanks